# Flex mobile Turning tabBar visible = True/False?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

i try to toggle tabBarvisible = true/false with the following code:

```
    protected function textArea_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (tabBarVisible="true")   {
                tabBarVisible="false";
            }
            else if (tabBarVisible="false") {
                tabBarVisible="true";   } 
        }
```

but only can get tabBarvisible="true" and when i click again nothing happen. the tabBarvisible won't turn to "false". is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you used only a single "=" sign so that actually assign the value instead of comparing it. Also, you don't need to use quotes for booleans.

```
tabBarVisible == true
```

Plus, as you're always toggling the value, you can simplify your code by simply inversing the value

```
protected function textArea_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tabBarVisible = !tabBarVisible;
}
```